# Shut-out precincts for Republican governor in 2021 New Jersey primary?

Tags: united-states, data-sources, republican-primary, governor, new-jersey

In 2008 and 2012, and to a lesser extent 2016, there were some precincts where Republicans got no votes. Example of a shut-out precinct in Louisiana's 2nd district special election, 2021:

[image: Shutout precinct, 09/36B]

I found that in Hudson County, about [88%](https://www.state.nj.us/state/elections/assets/pdf/election-results/2021/2021-unofficial-primary-results-governor.pdf) of people who voted in the governor primary voted for Murphy (the only democrat in the primary), and only 4,172 votes were cast for Republican candidates. Given the uneven distribution of votes (there were areas in Hudson County that were basically tied in 2016's presidential election and there were others where there were almost no Trump votes), I am fairly sure that they exist in Hudson and Essex Counties.

*Is there any documented evidence for these shutout precincts in the gubernatorial primary? If so, how many were there?* This is based on a related topic pertaining to [Philadelphia's elections](https://www.inquirer.com/philly/news/politics/20121112_In_59_Philadelphia_voting_wards__Mitt_Romney_got_zero_votes.html) and Mitt Romney.

Comment: I'm a little confused about why you would use a Louisiana example in a question about New Jersey.

Answer (score 1):

There were a total of 232 'shut-out' districts - 13 in [Campden County](https://www.camdencounty.com/wp-content/elections/primary2021/ContestBreakdown.pdf), 128 in [Essex County](https://results.enr.clarityelections.com/NJ/Essex/109583/web.276935), 1 in [Gloucester County](https://results.enr.clarityelections.com/NJ/Gloucester/109587/web.276935), 40 in [Hudson County](https://results.enr.clarityelections.com/NJ/Hudson/109797/web.276935), 11 in [Mercer County](https://results.enr.clarityelections.com/NJ/Mercer/109796/web.276935), 8 in [Middlesex County](http://www.middlesexcountynj.gov/Government/Pages/Live-Election-Results.aspx), 14 in [Passaic County](https://www.passaiccountynj.org/Election%20Results/2021/PrimarySOV_01.pdf), and 17 in [Union County](https://results.enr.clarityelections.com/NJ/Union/109795/web.276935).

In [Atlantic](https://results.enr.clarityelections.com/NJ/Atlantic/109581/web.276935), [Bergen](https://www.bergencountyclerk.org/_Content/pdf/ElectionResult/Print%20SOV%20Report%20w_%20VBMs(1).pdf), [Burlington](https://press.co.burlington.nj.us/PRESS/clerk/Election.aspx?op=ELE), [Cape May](https://results.enr.clarityelections.com/NJ/Cape_May/109965/web.276935), [Cumberland](https://results.enr.clarityelections.com/NJ/Cumberland/109582/web.276935), [Hunterdon](https://www.co.hunterdon.nj.us/election/2021/primary/Official%20Municipality%20P2021.pdf), [Monmouth](https://results.enr.clarityelections.com/NJ/Monmouth/109963/web.276935), [Morris](https://results.enr.clarityelections.com/NJ/Morris/109588/web.276935), [Ocean](https://results.enr.clarityelections.com/NJ/Ocean/109584/web.276935), [Salem](https://salemcountyclerk.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Salem-County_StatementOfVotesCast_Corrected-min.pdf), [Somerset](https://results.enr.clarityelections.com/NJ/Somerset/109590/web.276935), [Sussex](https://sussexcountyclerk.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/OFFICIAL-DISTRICT-SUMMARY.html), and [Warren](https://www.warrencountyvotes.com/home/showpublisheddocument/2478/637648300483830000) counties, every district returned at least one vote in the Republican primary.

A full list of 'shut-out' districts in the eight counties above follows.

```
---- CAMPDEN COUNTY ----
Camden City W1 D7
Camden City W1 D10
Camden City W2 D3
Camden City W2 D7
Camden City W2 D10
Camden City W2 D11
Camden City W3 D5
Camden City W3 D7
Camden City W3 D9
Camden City W4 D1
Lindenwold Dist 7
Pine Valley Dist 1
Tavistock Dist 1

---- ESSEX COUNTY ----
Bloomfield 2-3
Bloomfield 3-7
East Orange 1-1
East Orange 1-4
East Orange 1-5
East Orange 1-9
East Orange 1-10
East Orange 2-2
East Orange 2-3
East Orange 2-4
East Orange 2-7
East Orange 2-10
East Orange 2-11
East Orange 3-2
East Orange 3-4
East Orange 3-5
East Orange 3-6
East Orange 3-9
East Orange 3-11
East Orange 3-12
East Orange 3-14
East Orange 4-1
East Orange 4-2
East Orange 4-4
East Orange 4-6
East Orange 4-7
East Orange 4-13
East Orange 5-4
East Orange 5-7
East Orange 5-8
East Orange 5-9
East Orange 5-12
East Orange 5-13
Essex Fells 2
Irvington N-4
Irvington N-5
Irvington N-6
Irvington N-7
Irvington N-8
Irvington N-9
Irvington S-3
Irvington S-5
Irvington S-7
Irvington S-8
Irvington S-9
Irvington S-10
Irvington S-11
Irvington E-2
Irvington E-4
Irvington E-8
Irvington W-1
Irvington W-2
Irvington W-4
Irvington W-6
Maplewood 14
Millburn 15
Montclair 3-4
Newark N-12
Newark N-25
Newark N-38
Newark S-1
Newark S-4
Newark S-8
Newark S-11
Newark S-13
Newark S-17
Newark S-18
Newark S-19
Newark S-20
Newark S-22
Newark S-23
Newark S-24
Newark S-25
Newark S-29
Newark S-30
Newark S-32
Newark S-35
Newark S-37
Newark S-38
Newark S-41
Newark S-42
Newark S-46
Newark S-47
Newark S-48
Newark E-13
Newark E-18
Newark E-29
Newark W-6
Newark W-7
Newark W-10
Newark W-15
Newark W-20
Newark W-22
Newark W-23
Newark W-27
Newark W-28
Newark W-29
Newark W-30
Newark W-31
Newark W-32
Newark W-33
Newark W-34
Newark W-37
Newark W-38
Newark W-39
Newark W-41
Newark W-43
Newark W-46
Newark W-47
Newark C-4
Newark C-5
Newark C-6
Newark C-7
Newark C-12
Newark C-17
Newark C-22
Newark C-28
Newark C-39
Newark C-40
Newark C-42
Newark C-49
North Caldwell 2
Nutley 3-6
Orange E-1
Orange W-5
Orange W-6
South Orange 8
West Orange 1-3

---- GLOUCESTER COUNTY ----
Glassboro District 2

---- HUDSON COUNTY ----
East Newark Ward 1 District 1
East Newark Ward 1 District 2
Harrison Ward 4 District 1
Hoboken Ward 3 District 7
Hoboken Ward 4 District 5
Jersey City Ward A District 4
Jersey City Ward A District 13
Jersey City Ward A District 16
Jersey City Ward A District 19
Jersey City Ward A District 22
Jersey City Ward A District 31
Jersey City Ward A District 32
Jersey City Ward A District 33
Jersey City Ward B District 11
Jersey City Ward B District 14
Jersey City Ward B District 15
Jersey City Ward B District 26
Jersey City Ward C District 6
Jersey City Ward E District 2
Jersey City Ward E District 5
Jersey City Ward E District 11
Jersey City Ward F District 3
Jersey City Ward F District 5
Jersey City Ward F District 7
Jersey City Ward F District 8
Jersey City Ward F District 11
Jersey City Ward F District 12
Jersey City Ward F District 13
Jersey City Ward F District 14
Jersey City Ward F District 16
Jersey City Ward F District 17
Jersey City Ward F District 18
Jersey City Ward F District 19
Jersey City Ward F District 20
Jersey City Ward F District 24
Jersey City Ward F District 26
Jersey City Ward F District 29
North Bergen Ward 3 District 5
West New York Ward 2 District 6
West New York Ward 3 District 11

---- MERCER COUNTY ----
Trenton North 11
Trenton North 12
Trenton South 2
Trenton East 1
Trenton East 2
Trenton West 1
Trenton West 9
Trenton West 12
Trenton West 13
Trenton West 15
Trenton West 16

---- MIDDLESEX COUNTY ----
New Brunswick W4 D3
New Brunswick W5 D2
New Brunswick W6 D3
Perth Amboy W4 D2    
Perth Amboy W6 D6
Piscataway W3 D6
Piscataway W4 D4
Piscataway W4 D6

---- PASSAIC COUNTY ----
Little Falls 9
Passaic W2 D7
Passaic W2 D8
Passaic W4 D7
Paterson W1 D1
Paterson W1 D4
Paterson W1 D2
Paterson W3 D1
Paterson W3 D2
Paterson W3 D9
Paterson W4 D6
Paterson W4 D10
Paterson W5 D1
Paterson W5 D3

---- UNION COUNTY ----
Elizabeth Ward 1 District 1
Elizabeth Ward 1 District 8
Hillside Ward 3 District 1
Hillside Ward 4 District 4
Linden Ward 4 District 1
Linden Ward 4 District 2
Linden Ward 4 District 3
Linden Ward 5 District 4
Plainfield Ward 1 District 5
Plainfield Ward 1 District 6
Plainfield Ward 1 District 7
Plainfield Ward 3 District 5
Plainfield Ward 4 District 1
Plainfield Ward 4 District 3
Plainfield Ward 4 District 4
Rahway Ward 3 District 5
Union District 8
```